# @rownum not incrementing as expected (selecting n per group)

Tags: mysql, sql

What I'm expecting is for the tmp.rank to increment `1-10` for each `userid` before moving on to the next `userid` however all I'm getting is it staying on `1` for every record thus not limiting `10` items per `userid`.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong, most probably something simple and obvious or more likely using the SQL in a way it's not intended.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
        tmp.title,
        tmp.content,
        tmp.postid,
        tmp.userid,
        tmp.screenname,
        tmp.email
FROM
(
    SELECT
        qp.title,
        qp.content,
        qp.postid,
        ut.userid,
        ut.screenname,
        ut.email,
        qp.created,
        @rownum := IF( @prev = ut.userid, @rownum+1, 1 ) AS rank,
        @prev := ut.userid 
    FROM
        user_table AS ut JOIN (SELECT @rownum := NULL, @prev := 0) AS r ,
        qa_posts AS qp,
        qa_categories AS qc,
        expatsblog_country AS cc
    WHERE
        LOWER(ut.country_of_expat) = LOWER(qc.title)
        AND ut.setting_notifications IN (3)
        AND ut.valid=1
        AND ut.confirm_email = 1
        AND qc.categoryid = qp.categoryid
        AND qp.type='Q'
        AND DATE(qp.created)>=DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)  
    ORDER BY ut.userid,qp.created ASC
) AS tmp
WHERE tmp.rank < 10 
ORDER BY tmp.userid, tmp.created ASC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done many queries in the past, especially responding to posts out here regarding MySQL and @ variables.  One of the problems I've encountered is the return order of data when applying to the rows.

Your original query DID have an order by in the inner-most query, but I've encountered times where the @variable assignment is not truly respecting it, and resets the counter because it goes to some other (in this case) user, then later, encounters more records for the first and resets counter back to one even though it occurred later on.

Next, you are applying DISTINCT to the end.  I would try pulling DISTINCT to the inner-most so you are not getting 10 records for some key, same user and ending up with only 2 records returned.

That said, I would adjust the query to what I have below.  The inner-most just grabs DISTINCT on the columns you want, then apply the @variable assignments.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
      tmp.title,
      tmp.content,
      tmp.postid,
      tmp.userid,
      tmp.screenname,
      tmp.email,
      @rownum := IF( @prev = ut.userid, @rownum+1, 1 ) AS rank,
      @prev := ut.userid 
   FROM
      ( SELECT DISTINCT
              qp.title,
              qp.content,
              qp.postid,
              ut.userid,
              ut.screenname,
              ut.email
           FROM
              user_table AS ut
                 JOIN qa_categories AS qc
                    ON LOWER( ut.country_of_expat ) = LOWER( qc.title )
                    JOIN qa_posts AS qp
                       ON qc.categoryid = qp.categoryid
                      AND qp.type='Q'
                      AND DATE(qp.created)>=DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)
           WHERE
                  ut.setting_notifications = 3
              AND ut.valid = 1
              AND ut.confirm_email = 1
           ORDER BY 
              ut.userid,
              qp.created ASC ) AS tmp,
      ( SELECT @rownum := NULL, 
               @prev := 0) AS r
   HAVING
      tmp.rank < 10
   ORDER BY 
      tmp.userid
```

I did not see any references to "cc" being joined anywhere which would have
cause a Cartesian result giving a record for EACH entry in expatsblog_country
so I removed it... If it IS needed, put where applicable and put JOIN condition too.

( removed expatsblog_country AS cc )

Also, instead of a WHERE clause, I changed to a HAVING clause, so this way all returned records are CONSIDERED for the final result set.  This will ensure the @rownum will keep incrementing when it encounters a POSSIBLE entry, but having will throw all those greater than 10 out.

Finally, since the inner table was already pre-ordered by user and created date, you should not need the explicit re-ordering AGAIN in the outer... maybe just the UserID as I have it.

Comment: This worked! I figured that date() around qp.created was also negatively impacting the query. But a green tick for you. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am going to take a guess here at what the problem is.

You are combining two types of join syntax and that could be causing your issue.

You are using both a `JOIN` and then commas between your tables.  You are using a `JOIN` between the `user_table` and the user variables and then a comma between the remaining tables.

```
 FROM user_table AS ut JOIN (SELECT @rownum := NULL, @prev := 0) AS r ,
   qa_posts AS qp,
   qa_categories AS qc,
   expatsblog_country AS cc
```

While your `WHERE` clause includes the columns to join on for most tables. It looks like you have no join condition for the table `expatsblog_country`.  When you are joining tables, you should use one type of syntax and not mix them.

I would suggest something similar to this.  I did not see any join condition fo the `expatsblog_country` table so I used a `CROSS JOIN` to join those tables to the a subquery of the others. If you have a column to join the `expatsblog_country` to any of the others, then move that query into the subquery:

```
SELECT DISTINCT tmp.title,
    tmp.content,
    tmp.postid,
    tmp.userid,
    tmp.screenname,
    tmp.email
FROM
(
  SELECT src.title,
    src.content,
    src.postid,
    src.userid,
    src.screenname,
    src.email,
    src.created,
    @rownum := IF( @prev = src.userid, @rownum+1, 1 ) AS rank,
    @prev := src.userid 
  FROM
  (
    select ut.userid,
      ut.screenname,
      ut.email,
      qp.title,
      qp.content,
      qp.postid,
      qp.created
    from user_table AS ut
    join qa_categories AS qc
      on LOWER(ut.country_of_expat) = LOWER(qc.title)
    join qa_posts AS qp
      on qc.categoryid = qp.categoryid
    where ut.setting_notifications IN (3)
      and ut.valid=1
      and ut.confirm_email = 1
      and qp.type='Q'
      and DATE(qp.created)>=DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)  
  ) src
  CROSS JOIN 
  (
    SELECT @rownum := 0, @prev := 0
  ) AS r
  CROSS JOIN expatsblog_country AS cc
  ORDER BY src.userid, src.created ASC
) AS tmp
WHERE tmp.rank < 10 
ORDER BY tmp.userid, tmp.created ASC
```

Comment: This is still giving "1" as the rownum.

Comment: How does it decide which userid to put into to "@prev"? How do I get it to put it in the same order as the rest of the results...that is what seems to be the issue.

Comment: Can you create a SQL fiddle with your tables and some sample data? It might be easier to debug from there.

Comment: Thanks bluefeet - found what the issue was. See my answer below. Will +1 your answer for helping out.

Comment: @KB. I am glad that you figured it out. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
  ( SELECT @rownum := NULL, 
           @prev := 0) AS r
```

so that you initialize @rownum to 0, and @prev to NULL instead.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out what this was

1. expats_country was a not supposed to be part of the query

and more importantly:

1. the "DATE()" around qp.created was messing this up and the actual "last 24 hour" part of the query too. Removed this and it was fine.